# How to set a save point on freighter (or save the current game)?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I can't find a way to save my current game during the visit on my freighter using a save point.

Is it really not possible to use a [save point](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Save_Point)? Do you know some other possibility?

*(The only way I have found so far is to walk down to the starship, hop in & out. Just to try some buildings inside the freighter, this is really tedious.)*

Comment: A user on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/99zxa0/psa_save_point_on_freighter/) found a way during an experimental build. Although, that was a few months ago and it may have been patched

Comment: It is tedious, but that's the only way I am able to save in my freighter as well. I've only seen one person claim that they could drop a save point in one of the rooms they built, but this was a bug that was shortly after patched.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly no. The only way to save on the freighter is by entering and exiting your starship whenever you need to save.

Update :  It is now possible to construct a save point on freighters.

Comment: Since which update version is this possible? Is this one of the "Beyond" changes? Or one of the many patches since "Beyond"?

Comment: I believe it was the beyond update as i played before and after the update and tried to place a save point and could only do it after the beyond update.